# json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I cannot get any of the following code to work with the statements array I am working with.

```
if (!$allowed)
        {
            $output = array('success'=>false, 'message'=>'Insufficient User Access', 'args'=>$_POST);
        }
        else
        {
            $output = isset($_POST['data']) ? $output = call_user_func(array($controller, $_POST['request']), $_POST['data']) : call_user_func(array($controller, $_POST['request']));
        }

echo $output = $output ? json_encode($output) : json_encode(false);
```

This last statement is what is generating the error.  I have tried mb_chekc_encloding and iconv.  I cannot get either of these statements to work with making the $output actually show.

Comment: `$output = ... ? $output = `? That's just plain horrible...

Comment: @MarcB especially with the echo there as well

Comment: would be helpful to see what $output contains before the last line.

Comment: And what's actually in _POST; what encoding can you expect the values in _POST to have? You virtually couldn't have done a better job in "obfuscating" the script if you had tried on purpose ;-)

Comment: I did not write this.  I am just supporting this!!